# admin page of website only to be accessed by admin if someone tries to access it , it redirects to login-page

Tags: php, login-script, login-control

this is the code that I have written

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['authenticated'])){header("location:login.php");}
```

but this code is not working and it is being accessed

Comment: Do you authenticate only admin users? If no, there's your problem - it is only redirecting clients which are not authenticated, not those without the required authorisation.

Comment: Terminate the script after the header().... `if(!isset($_SESSION['authenticated'])){header("location:login.php"); exit; }`.... otherwise it will continue executing the remainder of the script.... header() is only telling PHP what headers should be sent, it doesn't actually send them until the script terminates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you set the variable to true or false?

```
if ($_SESSION['authenticated']) {
   // Admin page here...
} else {
   // Redirect to another page...
   header("Location: login.php");
   die();
}
```

EDIT:

The reason I say set it to true or false is that you ca log the user out by setting it to false. Rather than unsetting the variable.

EDIT:

- Removed the `= true` as it is not required.

You missed the capital L in the header function and you need to kill the page once you have redirected.

Replace

```
header('location:index.php');
```

with

```
header("Location: login.php");
die();
```

Comment: @AadisheshSharma Updated, that should solve your problem.

Comment: @AadisheshSharma Can you mark this the correct answer so others looking for the same problem can see this worked for you? Click the tick under the voting system. Thanks. Glad I could help!